# How to create a button at the end of a table that has the same width as the last row of the table in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Consider I have a table in html:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Home</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Service</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Contacts</td>
</tr>
```

Now I want just a button at the end of this table, that must have the same width (as expressed by its background color) as the last row of the table, which is `Contacts`. Now, how do I do that? When I create a button, it just have the width created by itself:

```
<button type="button" id='myBtn'>Click</button>
```

Now do I need to have a JavaScript code that sets the width of button `myBtn` element as that of 'Contacts' row?

Comment: Is there a reason that you dont want to do any css? You could easily set the width of of button with css and the problem is solved

Comment: why not use simple `<td onclick="myfunction();">Contacts</td>`, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `<button>` inside `<table>`:

Adding `display: block` and `width: 100%` to the button (with either CSS or JS) will make it expand to fill the width of its column:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

td {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  background: cyan;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Home</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Service</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contacts</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" id='myBtn'>Click</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want to do it with JS, it will be something like this:

```
const button = document.getElementById('myBtn')

button.style.width = '100%';
button.style.display = 'block';
```

#### `<button>` after `<table>`:

If you want the button outside the table, you can add a `<div>` with `display: inline-block` that wraps both the `<table>` and the `<button>`:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

td {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0;
}

button {
  background: cyan;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Home</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Service</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Contacts</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button type="button" id='myBtn'>Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But the button is in the last row of the table. I want the button to be outside the table. After I have finished the table with all the rows, the button comes up.